# How to count amount of child elements of a parent class

Tags: javascript

I have something like this.

```
function myFunction() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myID").childElementCount;
  alert(c);
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
function myFunction() {
  var c = document.getElementsByClass("myClass").childElementCount;
  alert(c);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `getElementsByClassName` (notice the `s`). You can access the number of matched elements by using `getElementsByClassName('my-class').length`

Comment: yeah typo ill fix that.

Comment: (please double-check my comment)

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName` returns a live *(not recommended - use .querySelectorAll('.myClass') instead)* NodeList. It would require a loop over the NodeList to get the `.children.length` if you don't want textNodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no getElementByClass but there is getElementsByClassName. However, it returns a collection of elements because you can have multiple elements with the same class. IDs however are limited to one per document.

So if you knew the index of the element in the collection, you could do something like this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
var c = els[0].childElementCount;
alert(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's `document.getElementsByClassName` which returns an `HTMLCollection` (as opposed to a single `Element`). An `HTMLCollection` can be converted to an array easily with the `[...x]` syntax.

So if you want the sum of child elements in all `.myClass` parents:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')]
  .reduce((sum, parent) => sum += parent.childElementCount, 0);
```

There's also the newer and more concise `document.querySelector[All]` functions:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')]
  .reduce((sum, parent) => sum += parent.childElementCount, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

@evolutionxbox has the working answer even though it is a comment. @evolutionxbox please make your comment an answer so that I can mark yours as correct.

This works.

```
function myFunction() {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass').length;
  alert(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to count all of the children of a certain className, here's how you would do that:

```
function countAllChildren(selector){
  let i = 0, q = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for(let n of q){
    i += n.children.length;
  }
  return i;
}
countAllChildren('.myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `childElementCount` on the parent element like this-

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[0].childElementCount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for that:

```
var count = $("#myID").children().length;
```